# Number of ways to form alternating subsequences of a binary string

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

There is a binary string S of the form "ababaab"
We have to find the number of ways to form subsequences of the form "ab" * n (where n is natural number)
For example if there is a string "abab" it will have 4 subsequences of the given type :
(1,2) , (3,4) , (1,4) , (1,2,3,4) will form "ab" and "abab"
I thought of calclating the number of "a" before every "b" in the string and then computing the answer from this but it does not work for all possibilities
Is there any way in combinatorics to account for this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a procedural approach.  Make an array of the length of your string.  Each entry that corresponds to an $a$ in the original string will get the number of substrings $(ab)*n\ a$ ending with that $a$, where $n=0$ is allowed.  Each entry that corresponds to a $b$ in the original string will get the number of substrings $(ab)*n$ ending with that $b$, where $n=0$ is not allowed.  Start at the first entry.  If it is an $a$, put in $1$.  If it is $b$, put in $0$.  At each subsequent entry, if it is an $a$ put in $1$ more that the sum of the previous $b$ entries.  You can accumulate this as you go so you don't have to add it each time.  If it is $b$ put in the sum of all the previous $a$ entries.  Your final answer is the sum of all the $b$ entries.  This gives an answer in time linear in the length of the string.

Comment: Great solution Ross.